# Creating a UIControl that is a MTKView or otherwise uses Metal for rendering

Tags: xcode, uikit, metal

I am trying to do some custom UIControls that use metal for their rendering. These will be used in a UIKit based interface. There will be about 3 different ones on the screen at a time so I am figuring MTKView might be the right choice here.

At all costs I want to save CPU and GPU effort by not needlessly using CPU or GPU energy to update these views when they are not being explicitly edited. They are not animated.

My problem is that I would like these to be UIControls so that the classes I make can easily be used from InterfaceBuilder and can respond, send and delegate UIEvents.

Swift does not support multiple inheritance so how do I do this? Am I even attempting the right thing?

Comment: I haven't done it, but could you subclass `UIControl` and add one or more `MTKView`s or `CAMetalLayer`s that you draw into whenever your view needs to redraw? You might wind up with a few frames of lag, but it seems like this would be possible and meet your criteria.

Comment: As I understand it, UIKit is already built on Metal in modern versions of iOS. What are you trying to achieve that you can't with normal techniques?

Comment: Fancy color gradients

Answer (score 0):

you will probably use `UIControl` with the knowledge that its a subclass of `UIView`. So you could implement a Boolean property in your UIControl that is storing if Metal can be used and providing a fallback for other techniques to render the content in case metal is not available.

You need to consider when you allocate more than one of your custom made UIControls, Metal/GPU will render them one by one and not in parallel unless you define a global renderer that could render all your controls graphics at once placed as 'almost frontmost' layer of your basic UIView. You will want to make use of transparency with

```
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0,0,0,0);
```

and also think about that touch/event handling could be disturbed by such a layer. Which all could be handled nicely. Or you would implement this in your base View and then set i.e. Uniforms in the mentioned global renderer with the use of the UIControls

As a starting point you would make use of something like

```
@interface yourUIControl {
    MTKView * mtkview;
    YourMetalRenderer * _yourRenderer;
    BOOL _isMetalDriven;
}
@end

@implementation yourUIControl

-(BOOL)isMetalPerforming:(CGRect)frame {
    mtkview = [[MTKView alloc] init];
    [MTKView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    mtkview.preferredFramesPerSecond = 24;
    mtkview.presentsWithTransaction = NO;
    mtkview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    mtkview.frame = frame;
    mtkview.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    if(!mtkview.device) {
        NSLog(@"Metal is not supported on this device");
        return NO;
    } else {
        _yourRenderer = [[YourMetalRenderer alloc] initWithMetalKitView:mtkview];
        if (!_yourRenderer) {
            NSLog(@"Renderer failed initialization");
            return NO;
        } else {
            [_yourRenderer mtkView:mtkview drawableSizeWillChange:mtkview.drawableSize];
            mtkview.delegate = _yourRenderer;
            [self addSubview:mtkview];
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

and then when initializing your custom UIControl set your BOOL property like so

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) ) return nil;
    // ask for the renderer and set BOOL property
    _isMetalDriven = [self isMetalPerforming:frame];
    // handling fallback if i.e. metal is not performing
    if (!_isMetalDriven) {
       // your classic layer technique to create UIControls content here.
       // dont forget when the control is changed in some way, you will forward
       // changes to _yourRenderer (i.e. Uniform properties) OR to classic handling  
    }
    //your other UIControl code
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    if (!_isMetalDriven) { 
        //classic control layout here..

    } else {
        //metal backed layout here..
        mtkview.frame = self.frame; //i.e.
    }
}

@end
```

you can set `pause` the renderer to YES and NO if needed or even make its rendering process depending on DisplayLink or setNeedsDisplay with appropriate properties from your mtkView

your `CAMetalLayer` would exist then in `mtkview.layer`